# How to include BackgroundPatternColor or HighlightColor in a Word Style definition?

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-style

Since the Highlight color palette in Ms-Office/Word is very limited, in some Word documents we use BackgroundPatternColor to give the background color of the text.

Question:
I would like to define a custom Style as a spinoff of the Normal Style, that includes a custom background color.
In the Style definition dialogue I did not find any option where I can include the bgcolor of the selection.
Any ideas?

Note: The only option close to that is the so called Border>Shading>Fill Color, but that always spans to the full line/paragraph, cannot be applied to less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the background color, but if you don't want it coloring the entire paragraph then you must create a *character* style and set the color for its `.Font` property.

(Note: you could also create a so-called "linked" style, that can be use for both paragraph and font formatting, but these are generally frowned upon in professional documentation circles.)

Here's an example

```
Sub ChangeStyleColor()
    Dim styl As word.style
    Dim stylName As String
    Dim color As word.WdColor

    stylName = "fontBlueBackground"
    color = wdColorAqua

    ' the style might not exist - if not, create it
    On Error Resume Next
    Set styl = ActiveDocument.styles(stylName)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If styl Is Nothing Then
        Set styl = ActiveDocument.styles.Add(stylName, word.WdStyleType.wdStyleTypeCharacter)
        styl.BaseStyle = word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleDefaultParagraphFont
    End If

    CharStyleBackgroundColor styl, color

End Sub

Sub CharStyleBackgroundColor(styl As word.style, color As word.WdColor)
    styl.Font.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = color
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for this hint. I have tested it and then digged a bit further into this direction. https://www.greatcirclelearning.com/new-blog/2017/12/14/linked-styles-working-with-them-in-microsoft-word  ; From that i see, that I dont need to create a toatally new, separate CharacterStyle, already existing Linked-styles (managed automatically in latest Words) can just as well be updated with the same method.(styl.font)

Comment: @ÁdámBukovinszki Yes, I mentioned linked styles in my Answer, with the remark that they are frowned on by professional documentation people. That's the reason I proposed a separate Character style. "Convenience" is a point of view...

Answer (score 0):

Until somebody comes up with an inbuilt answer
as usual, I will use a workaround:

I will use custom macros as custom Styles for such cases, and i will put these macros on the ribbon into an m-styles folder.
For example:

```
Sub F_HáttérSzín_Hupilila()
    Dim SzínKód As Variant
    SzínKód = 13444920
    Selection.Font.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = SzínKód
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

by right clicking and adding the background adds the background colour

Comment: Can you please be a tiny bit more specific? 
Are you talking also about saving Background color to a STYLE in MsWord?

Comment: I mean, i can ofcourse set the bg-color manually for a selected text, but when i select it and click on Create a Style, the bg-color is not saved with it, nor can I set it manually in the Modify dialogue.